# How to retrieve data outside of function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, object, ecmascript-6

I am using `xml2js` node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

I am parsing `XML` data into `JSON`

But how do I get the value outside this function?

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

// My XML Data
var xml = "<root>my xml data</root>"

// Function to parse xml to json
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

I am looking to get the parsed value `result` out of the function so that I can use it at different components?

> const jsonOutput = result;

Comment: Note, you accepted the below answer, but that will *not* work in m,any circumstances unless you can *guarantee* that the `parseString` callback will finish before you try to use `stringResult`. In many cases though, you won't have such a guarantee. Pleae read the duplicate post. It's more complicated, but it shows how you can handle this in a fool-proof way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `result` outside your `parseString` function:

```
var stringResult;

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
    stringResult = result;
});
```

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, this will get the results out of the function, but depending on how `stringResult` is accessed, it may not be set by the time it's used.

Comment: How should I fix it then @Carcigenicate?

Comment: That's what's explained in the duplicate. You could string callbacks or promises or a similar mechanism.

Comment: @Carcigenicate should I set a timeer before I move to next function? would that help? or should I check if there are any valid data before I use the `result` value?